# Удалить и восстановить блок div через jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Доброго времени суток.

Никак не получается удалить и восстановить блок в зависимости от разрешения экрана. Задача: сделать так, чтобы блок .h-about-mobile удалялся при разрешении экрана больше 768px и восстанавливался при разрешении равном 768px или меньше.

Пробовал вот такой код, где .for-mobile был родительским блоком:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $hideBlock = $('.h-about-mobile');
  var $contentWrap = $('.for-mobile');

  function mobileNav() {
    var $mobileWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($mobileWidth > 768) {
      $hideBlock.detach();
    } else {
      $contentWrap.append($hideBlock);
    }
  }
  mobileNav();
$(document).ready(function() {
  mobileNav();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  mobileNav();
});
});
```

Также пробовал вот так попроще:

```
var elem = $('.h-about-mobile');
var $mobileWidth = $(window).width();
if ($mobileWidth > 768) {
elem.detach();
} else {
elem.appendTo('body');
```

Не работает, блок так и остаётся на месте. Подскажите, что поправить в коде? Каков будет рабочий вариант?

Comment: Это же надо делать на CSS, или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

а вы попробуйте переменные без `$` называть - у нас тут все таки javascript, а не php ;-)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let hideBlock = $('.h-about-mobile');
  let contentWrap = $('.for-mobile');

  function mobileNav() {
    let mobileWidth = $(window).width();
    if (mobileWidth > 768) {
      hideBlock.detach();
    } else {
      contentWrap.append(hideBlock);
    }
  }
  mobileNav();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    mobileNav();
  });
});
```

```css
.h-about-mobile {
  width:    50px;
  height:   50px;
  
  background: orange;
}

.for-mobile {
  width:    200px;
  height:   100px;
  
  border:   1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = 'for-mobile'><div class = 'h-about-mobile'></div></div>
```

P.S.

на данном сайте эффекта не будет видно - потому что окно меньшего размера (меньше 768)

Comment: `а вы попробуйте переменные без $ называть` что это изменит?

Comment: @Zhihar доллар , к сожалению, никак не влияет на работу скрипта. Хотя (мало ли, может я тупой) я попробовал, всё же. Нет, не работает)

Comment: почему у меня работает? на данном сайте не работает, потому что пример выводится в меньшего размера окне (у меня 600+ пикселей), а ваша функция `$(window).width()` получает все таки не размер экрана монитора, если вы запустите мой код в редакторе на данном сайте и уменьшите размер окна (например войдете в режим отладки по F12) - то все будет работать - блок то будет появляться то будет уменьшаться

Comment: @Zhihar Тут что-то реально не работает, но в кодпэн перенёс, заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: тогда проверьте - может у вас еще дополнительно что-то вызывает сбои, тут то совсем маленький пример

Answer (score 0):

Или на CSS

```css
.block {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.less767 {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { /** Когда экран меньше 767 px, применить эти стили **/
  .more767 {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .less767 {
    display: block;
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="less767 block">
  Экран меньше < 767
</div>

<div class="more767 block">
  Экран больше > 767
</div>
```